# Lightmap not working in Unity Prefabs

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to do a 30 level gameplay in unity. To reduce the size I want to use prefabs. So path to travel is made as parts and kept prefabed. Using these parts I have made many levels and these are also kept as prefabs. The problem is for each level I have used individual light maps. Its also included in level prefabs(baked). ie, every prefab contains level paths and lights(baked).
But am not getting the preferred lightmap from the prefab. What do I need to do to make this happen?